# Optional non-terminals in production

Tags: c++, parsing, recursive-descent

Does anyone know how to handle the following case?

```
if-section:
    if-group [ elif-groups ] [ else-group ] endif-line

if-group:
    ....

elif-groups:
    elif-group
    elif-groups elif-group

elif-group:
    "#" "elif" constant-expression new-line [ group ]

else-group:
    "#" "else" new-line [ group ]

endif-line:
    "#" "endif" new-line
```

All non-terminals in if-section after if-group starting with "#". I think in this case there is left-factoring impossible. Are there any "default solutions" to identify if I have to call one of the both (or both) optional non-terminals?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear what needs handling. You can't distinguish between `[ elif-groups ]` and  `[ else-group ]` when you've seen just `#`, no. But if you look ahead another token, you can. I.e. two tokens is enough to decide.

This isn't the worse bit of C++ grammar by far.

Comment: Mh okay. What is the worse bit of the C++ Grammar? The Decision between parsing a declaration or expression? Thank you.

Comment: A few minutes ago I saw some strange or very hard to parse constructs in the grammar of C (not C++).
assignment-expression:
conditional-expression |
unary-expression assignment-operator assignment-expression
can not converted to a LL(1) grammar. conditional-expression and unary-expression are the same, expect that unary-expression skips a few grammar-nodes :/. So there isn't a opportunity to left-factoring i think?

Comment: @sknine: Sorry, can't recall that bit of theory